# In vs to with locations

Tags: prepositions

I can't quite understand when it is correct to say "in" or "to" while speaking about location and destination. What is the difference between "We had a trip to Romania" and "we had a trip in Romania"? I always feel that the right way is "to", but I see a lot of people using the "in" version and it gets me puzzled every time. Can anyone explain that to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We had a trip to Romania means that you went on an excursion to Romania from somewhere else, you may have been domiciled somewhere else or on vacation somewhere else or on a business somewhere else.

We had a trip in Romania means that you went on an excursion while you were in Romania, you may have been on vacation there or on business there or domiciled there at the time.

Comment: Chris M, thank you! That actually explains a lot :)

Comment: This question is hardly suitable for ELU, a site for linguists.